# 'Dict.get()' equivalent for pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

Does anyone know if there's an equivalent for the `Dict.get()` method for pandas Series? I've got a series that looks like this:

```
In [25]: s1
Out[25]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

And I'd like to return a default value, such as 0, if I try to access an index that isn't there. For example, I'd like `s1.ix['z']` to return `0` instead of `KeyError`. I know pandas has great support for dealing with missing values in other circumstances, but I couldn't find anything specifically about this.

Thank you!

Comment: You could always `try` to get the item and handle the exception yourself.  It's only an extra 3 lines of code :-) -- But, admittedly, I don't know pandas so ...

Comment: That's true, but would be pretty clunky. In my case, I'm accessing multiple Series per line, so that would get ugly pretty fast.

Comment: Oops.. I think `s.get('z', 0)` should do this, but there's a bug in `pandas`.. it's only catching KeyErrors and ValueErrors, not IndexErrors. :-/  I'll submit a pull request..

Comment: @DSM: `s1.get('z', 0)` works using version 0.14.0. (It catches KeyError and ValueError).

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: @unutbu: I should have been more clear.  Try `s.get(3, 0)` (with the OP's Series.)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, pandas implements `get` directly for Series.

So `s1.get('x', 0)` would return `0`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make sense of the previous answers since they were missing the reference to the dict you use as source. Here is my answer, works for me at least

```
In[12]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'z'])
        my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
        result = s1.index.map(my_dict).fillna(0)
        new_series = pd.Series(result, index=s1.index)
        new_series

Out[13]: 
a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
z    0.0
dtype: float64
```